# Spark.table() with limit seems to reads whole table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read the first 20000 rows of a large table (10bil+ rows) from spark so I use the following lines of code.

```
df = spark.table("large_table").limit(20000).repartition(1)
df.explain()
```

And the explain plan looks like this.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(1)
+- *(2) GlobalLimit 20000
   +- Exchange SinglePartition
      +- *(1) LocalLimit 20000
         +- *(1) FileScan parquet large_table[...]
```

But when I try to write this df into a new table, it seems to kick off an insane number of tasks trying to read the whole table first and then begin writing to the final table! Why does spark not read only the first few files and get the row limit?

Comment: How the table is defined? What is the average number of record partition?

Comment: Moreover, limit() returns a DataSet, right? What version of Spark you have?

Comment: The table is written from hive. If I add a where clause with a specific partition, it reads only that partition and then does a limit and there is plenty more than those rows per partition. But my question is, irrespective of what the number of partitions or how many files there are, it shouldnt be reading the whole table.

Comment: limit() returns a dataset yes. But I am saving that to a table. I am using spark 2.3.1